# TFrame component : Resource not found

Tags: delphi, components, resources, tframe, dfm

Tool: Delphi 6 Pro

I created a new component in my main components package that is a descendant of TFrame using the Component -> New Component option.  When I try to draw the component on a form during design time I get a "Resource {component class name} not found" error.  I tried adding the line {$R *.dfm} to the component unit just after the "implementation" declaration and that didn't work.  (I did recompile the host package first).  I even tried copying over a DFM from another frame and then renaming everything to sync up with the main unit including the DFM file name itself.  That didn't work either.

I want to have the TFrame descendant as a Component instead of just creating a new TFrame variant because I want to add properties to it that show up in the Property Editor at design time.  Is there a way to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For registering frames as components see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735521/how-to-improve-the-use-of-delphi-frames

Comment: Thanks Sertac.  That's a good reference.